# What is the benefit of setting the domain of a property in Jena?

Tags: java, jena, semantic-web, owl

First, I create two class as below.

```
OntClass  Class1 = ontModel.getOntClass(prefix+"Class1");
OntClass Class2 = ontModel.createClass( prefix+"Class2" );
```

Then,  I create a property and set its domain and range as below.

```
DatatypeProperty property = ontModel.createDatatypeProperty(prefix+"property1");
property.addDomain(Class2);
property.addRange(Class2);
```

Then, I create a individual of class1.

```
Individual ind1 = ontModel.createIndividual( prefix+ "ind1",class1);
```

At last, I add the property to the individual.

```
ind1.addProperty(property, "SSSSSS");
```

Here is my question. Now that I have defined the domain and range of the property, how can the individual of another class have this property successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in OWL are not all disjoint, so an individual can belong to multiple classes.

Domains and ranges for properties to not stop you from using the properties on individuals not belonging already to the domain or range; making such assertions will simply enable a reasoner to infer that the individual also belongs to the class specified as domain.

The only case in which this is "unsuccessful" is when the domain class and any other class the individual is inferred to belong to are also declared as disjoint, or can be inferred to be disjoint - in that case, an individual belonging to both causes an inconsistency.

Comment: Note: this is not Jena specific, it is common to all OWL tools.